# How to pass payload to Javascript component in Mulesoft?

Tags: javascript, mulesoft

[image]

How to get all the payload from http post to Javascript component in Mulesoft?

Answer (score 1):

The payload is automatically available in the scripting component as the keyword `payload`:

```
    <scripting:execute engine="JavaScript" doc:name="Execute">
        <scripting:code >var x = payload;</scripting:code>
    </scripting:execute>
```

To decouple your script from mule internal keywords, you can pass in a list of parameters instead in the form of a dataweave map of key:value pairs:

```
    <scripting:execute engine="JavaScript" doc:name="Execute">
        <scripting:code >var x = myVar;</scripting:code>
        <scripting:parameters ><![CDATA[#[{'myVar': payload}]]]></scripting:parameters>
    </scripting:execute>
```